# How to identify inside screen resolution the multiple display that is enabled?

Tags: winapi, cmd, screen, monitoring, multiple-monitors

I've searched all over Google but found no answer, so If someone knows It would be very thankful!

I want to use command line or some WinApi to check the state of the multiple display.
For example : If I set : "extended screen" or "duplicate screen" I want to be able to verify it.
Just have no idea where to start.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the WinAPI EnumDisplayMonitors function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
BOOL EnumDisplayMonitors(
  _In_  HDC hdc,
  _In_  LPCRECT lprcClip,
  _In_  MONITORENUMPROC lpfnEnum,
  _In_  LPARAM dwData
);
```

You need to call this function setting the first 2 parameters to NULL like this:

```
EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MyPaintEnumProc, 0);

//Enumerates all display monitors.
//The callback function receives a NULL HDC.
```

Now you have your MonitorEnumProc callback function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(
  _In_  HMONITOR hMonitor,
  _In_  HDC hdcMonitor,
  _In_  LPRECT lprcMonitor,
  _In_  LPARAM dwData
);
```

You wiil get filled lprcMonitor back:

> A pointer to a RECT structure.
>       If hdcMonitor is non-NULL, this rectangle is the intersection of the clipping area of the device context identified by hdcMonitor and
>   the display monitor rectangle. The rectangle coordinates are
>   device-context coordinates.
>
> ```
> If hdcMonitor is NULL, this rectangle is the display monitor rectangle. The rectangle coordinates are virtual-screen coordinates.
> ```

Based on this values for ALL monitors you can decide whether you have an extended mode (the rects are different) or the duplicate (they are equal).

HTH - good luck!

Comment: Thanks! just a small q , what is MyPaintEnumProc? VS doesn't recognize it. what type should it be? and how is it connected to the CallBack function? (it's my first c++ program sorry for the "beginners" questions)

Comment: MyPaintEnumProc is the pointer to your call-back function (a kind of MonitorEnumProc). Before you call EnumDisplayMonitors you need to declare it: BOOL CALLBACK MyPaintEnumProc (
  HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData
) { /* do something */ }

Comment: Can I use this function to identify also if only the projector is working ?  of if I;m using only main monitor while having 2 monitors available?